# neo4j look for users by radius

Tags: neo4j, geolocation, cypher

I am a new noob to `neo4j`. this is my second day.
Pretty excited about the technology and have many questions. please be patient ☺️

in the desired application, users can view uses around them
(only in cases where both users are visible to each other using the `location_radius` ) property

for this exercise, I generated `100,000` users with a random location in my country inside `MySql`. and they are imported to `neo4j` (relationships are created manually by python neo4j)

**1st attempt:**

create a relationship between users that are visible by the desire criteria.

a. insert all users to neo4j (fast)
b. one by one create relationships by looking at the location of criteria of previous users (slow process, probably doing it wrong)
this is still running, currently 13,987 nodes. 22,460,068 relationships..... is this wrong a idea?

```
MATCH (src_u:User {user_id:1})-[:IN_SEARCH]-(u:User)
RETURN src_u, u
```

**2nd attempt**  (one the same schema)

Run the query without using the relationships

```
MATCH (me:User {user_id:1}),(u:User)
WHERE u.user_id <> 1
AND me.gender <> u.gender
AND distance(me.location, u.location) < me.location_radius 
AND distance(me.location, u.location) < u.location_radius
RETURN u
```

**3rd attempt**

The same thing but try to optimize the 2nd attempt, will this query optimize the 2nd attempt?

```
MATCH (me:User {user_id:1})
WITH me
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE u.user_id <> 1
AND me.gender <> u.gender
WITH me, u, distance(me.location, u.location) as d 
WHERE d < me.location_radius AND d < u.location_radius
RETURN u
```

**My questions are:**

1. is the **1st attempt** is the wrong way to go, dose millions of relationships is a wrong idea?
2. dose **2/3 attempt** are superior to **1st attempt**?
3. dose the **3rd attempt** dose any optimization for the **2nd attempt**?
4. dose a grid of "Station" `(Station {point(...)}` nodes (each kilometer square) and connecting users to the closest Station help (in case if **1st attempt** is too much.)?
5. `neo4j` can replace the DB completely?, is it a good practice to store the RAW data in a relational database?

---

The User create query:

```
MERGE (u:User {user_id:$user_id})
ON CREATE SET u.name=$name, u.gender=$gender, u.location=point({latitude:$latitude,longitude:$longitude}), u.location_radius=$location_radius
RETURN u
```

thank you

shay

Comment: You seem to be saying that you want to "create" relationships.But none of your queries are trying to create any relationships, and none are trying to return relationships either.

Comment: thank you @cybersam for you response. the question was referring to finding nodes around each other by geo location. should I create relationship between them or select them. if so are the queries different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating/deleting "nearness" relationships between *all* `User`s is not practical, as you have seen, especially if you need to do that continuously. Generally speaking, relationships should be used when you expect relatively stable connections between nodes. It does not make sense to create/delete a lot relationships to keep track of the results of a continuously running process -- especially if you only care about the results for a handful of `User`s.

Instead, you should create a [spatial index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/spatial/#cypher-spatial-index) on `:User(location)`:

```
CREATE INDEX user_distance FOR (u:User) ON (u.location)
```

That can speed up certain `distance` queries. For example, [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) shows that the following query would use that spatial index (at least in neo4j 4.0.4). *You should always profile your queries to help optimize them, and to make sure they remain optimized after version changes.*

```
MATCH (p:User), (q:User)
WHERE
  p.user_id = 1 AND
  p.location_radius > distance(p.location, q.location) < q.location_radius
RETURN p, COLLECT(q) AS others_nearby
```